# How to make http call and don't subscribe to response

Tags: http, angular, observable

I need to make multiple http calls and don't subscribe to response (let's assume the response is always `204`). Looks like Angular will not make http request if subscription list is empty. How to force it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observables are lazy and don't do anything unless `subscribe()` is called.
You don't need to do anything though when data arrives

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe()
```

will do.

Comment: Gunter, I have a scenario where the user submits a request, that takes too long to complete. If I do the above and the user navigates to some other route, will the request be cancelled?

Comment: Also, is there a way to show that the request has been completed, even after the user has routed away from the component that he sent the request from?

Comment: I don't think the request will be canceled. You can store the subscription `this.subsr = this.http.get(url).subscribe();` and then in `ngOnDestroy() { this.subsr.unsubscribe(); }`. If the request will be cancelled depends on the implementation of `Http` or `HttpClient`, but at least your code will not be called anymore in case a response arrives.